# Matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How to find a **matrix** of linear transformation  $f: R^n \to Mat^{(n,n)} $ .

Let's say we do $f: R^2 \to Mat^{(2,2)} $ given by $f(x,y)= \begin{bmatrix}x & 2y\\x+y & x\end{bmatrix}$

We calculate image of canonical basis $f(1,0)= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $f(0,1)= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Now the problematic part, ever since when caltulating matrix from vectors $R^n \to R^m$ the approach is to transpose images of standard base $(f(1,0,...,0)^{T} | f(0,1,...,0)^{T}| f(0,0,...,1)^{T})$. We can solve the $R \to Mat$ problem by using $\alpha(1,0)+\beta(0,1) = \alpha f(1,0)+\beta(0,1)$, of course, but is there any way how to shrink the vector so we can succeed something like $(A^T|B^T|C^T...)$?

Comment: What is the "standard" base in $Mat^{(2,2)}$?

Comment: I think this $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} $ since it's defacto caconical base in matrices; but there is no necessity for having that since you plug your own base $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ and you get image of it.

Comment: you plug in the basis vectors of $R^2$ into $f$ and expand the images in a basis of $Mat^{(2,2)}$.

Comment: I don't know if I undestand what you mean, but I'm stuck on that, I can't carry on 
$A(f) = (f(1,0)^T)|f(0,1)^T)=(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T | \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T) =(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}| \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\2 & 0\end{bmatrix})=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a linear transformation from a vector space of dimension $2$ to vector space of dimension $4$, so its matrix will be of the order $4\times 2$. Now the basis of the space of Matrices of order $2\times 2$ is $\{e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}\}$ where $e_{ij} = 1$ at the $ij^{\text{th}}$ entry and $0$ at all other places. So $f(1,0) = e_{11} + e_{21} + e_{22}$ and $f(0,1) = 2e_{12} + e_{21}$ so from here your matrix will be

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2\\1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE , please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference)  when typing.